# Sharepoint 2010 - Alert on "Tags & Notes" in a library

Tags: sharepoint-2010, tags, alert

Is it possible to receive Alerts in Sharepoint  2010 when users add Tags or Notes in a Sharepoint Library?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box you will receive a notification in your newsfeed if the person is a colleague or if they used a tag that you have added as an interest.

Comment: Thanks Doug;  I need the notification to be mailed or SMS'ed, the same way the standard alerts on the library work.  Any idea how this can be done; preferably programmatically?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible. You may want to look at NewsGator and see if they have a solution for this.